# Hint for real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose that $f$ is one-to-one and continuous on [$a,b$]. Prove that $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on [$a,b$].

Comment: Suppose it weren't. Use the intermediate value theorem to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Use the intermediate-value theorem to get a contradiction if you assume
$$\exists x,y \in [a,b] : f'(x) < 0 \wedge f'(y) > 0$$
Use Weierstraß to acqurie a differentiable function with norm arbitrarily close to $f$.

Comment: **Most** (in the sense that the complement is of the first category) elements of $C^0([a,b])$ are nowhere differentiable.

Comment: @All sorry, updated argument. Weierstraß works here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Go by contradiction. If its not monotone then we have some $p \le q \le r$ such that

$$f(p) \ge f(q) \le f(r)$$

Then apply the intermediate value theorem to get a contradiction.